# Removing any images & text boxes when reading excel file

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I use the following code with the objective to remove any images & text boxes within the worksheet and drop the first 6 rows that are blank. This code works perfectly when the only existing sheet is the one that I apply the code. In reality the file has 5 worksheets and then it's when I get the following error message.

Code used:

```
df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', skiprows=range(5))

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Error message:

```
ValueError: Value does not match pattern {[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\}
```

How can I modify the code so that it can only apply that code to just only one worksheet?

Comment: Hi, why not use `sheet_name="name of worksheet"` when calling `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: @Laurent That was my initial approach but I got the same exact error as shown above. I am still confused over it